# ngModel not updating with search input clear button in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, search

When using an input type="search" field with AngularJS in IE 9, 10 or 11. When you click the clear / cancel button rendered in Internet Explorer the model value does not reset to `''` or `undefined`.

Example HTML:

```
<input ng-model="searchVal" type="search">
<p>searchVal = {{ searchVal }}</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zE2qMMfaJK11KYfUWZzr?p=preview

It works fine in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for me

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="name" id="search" />
```

```js
$("#search").bind("mouseup", function(e){
    var $input = $(this),
        oldValue = $input.val();

    if (oldValue == "") return;

    setTimeout(function(){
        var newValue = $input.val();
        if (newValue == ""){
            $scope.name="";
            $scope.$apply();
        }
      }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with IE, that can only be fixed with slightly hacky workarounds For example: Adding a custom mouse event listener, and also detecting a press of the ESC key.

See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11193

Supposedly this is fixed in MS Edge but I can't verify that.